# OpenSSL: Does Wireshark count "Cipher Suites Length" or is the length transmitted from Client to Server?

Tags: networking, ssl, openssl, wireshark

In the client hello, the client sends a set of ciphers to the client. Now, the number of ciphers that are sent from the client to server is specified in Wireshark, as can be seen in the highlighted part below.

[image]

Is this length sent by the client to the server, or does wireshark simply count the number of bytes and calculate the length itself?

If the length is sent from the client to the server, in which part of the `openssl` code is it being sent? Which variable contains the length?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this length sent by the client to the server, or does wireshark simply count the number of bytes and calculate the length itself?

If you would look down to the actual bytes marked when you select the entry about cipher suites length, then you would see the 2 bytes used to specify the length.

Answer (score 0):

Every SSL message contains a type and a length, including this one.

Answer (score 0):

Length is decided based on what ciphers are being used for encryption. 
An SSL/TLS client application using openssl library can configure this by using [SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(...) or SSL_set_cipher_list(...)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) API.

Length value looks to be set by `ssl3_client_hello()` in [openssl/ssl/s3_clnt.c](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/ssl/s3_clnt.c) file.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm more than 2 years late to the party, but I had the same doubt and ended up here. Since there is no further explanation I will elaborate a little, for anyone bumping into this:

As you can see in Wireshark's statusbar when you click on the Cipher Suites Length field, this field contains the length (in bytes) of the Cipher Suites field. Since each Cipher Suite is composed of 2 bytes, the Cipher Suites Length is generally 2x the number of Cipher Suites following (92 vs 46 in this case).